# how to call dll in fortran

Tags: dll, fortran

I have one dll file which contains a function "ProcessWeather" and want to call this function in a fortran code, as shown below:

```
PROGRAM myprog
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT :: EPLUSWTH


INTERFACE

  SUBROUTINE ProcessWeather(InType,OutType,InFileName,OutFileName,ErrFlag)

    CHARACTER(len=*), INTENT(IN) :: InType       ! InputFile Type
    CHARACTER(len=*), INTENT(IN) :: OutType      ! OutputFile Type
    CHARACTER(len=*), INTENT(IN) :: InFileName   ! InputFile Name (Full path)
    CHARACTER(len=*), INTENT(IN) :: OutFileName  ! OutputFileName (Full path)
    REAL(4), INTENT(OUT)  :: ErrFlag      ! If errors are found,
                                                 ! set to true and put
                                                 ! description put in file.
 END SUBROUTINE
END INTERFACE
END PROGRAM
```

The dll file is put to the same place where I put the fortran file to.
When I compile the fortran code, I got the following error:
undefined reference to processweather_

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is just the interface - is the implementation compiled into the DLL as well?

Comment: No, I don't have the source code for the dll file and really have no clue about how to refer the dll file in the fortran code since I am totally new to fortran. Could you please let me know how to do so?

Comment: You can use an application like depends or any dll Walker to check info on the routine. Also, is it interoperable? Does it have any suffix or prefix (like underscore or @)? What's the passing mechanism, stdcall or cdecl...?

Comment: I don't have too much information about the DLL rather the function name and the argument list. Therefore I am not sure if I can provide the information you mentioned. By the way, just one quick question, does !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT :: EPLUSWTH have any effort at all in gfortran?

Comment: That particular $DEC or $MS directive just tells the linker what to stick in the lookup table so that the functions in the DLL can be found when the linker tries to link the program or the run-time loader tries to dynamically link the program at load time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling with gfortran (as your comment seem to suggest) the `!$DEC` directives will be ignored. But you could use the [GCC directives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ATTRIBUTES-directive.html), namely the `ATTRIBUTES` directive and declare the attribute `DLLIMPORT` in it.

You could also just use the standard `bind(C, name="the_name")`. Also, as far as I remember, GCC did not require any attributes to make symbols externally visible when creating a DLL.